# "An insecure overload of" warning

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I have the following code:

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path_to_xml, FileMode.Open))
{
    using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fs))
    {
        // Do something with xr
    }
}
```

and I receive warning

> CA3075: An insecure overload of XmlReader.Create which does not accept
>   an XmlReaderSettings argument

If I change the Create statement and add an XmlReaderSettings like so:

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fs, new XmlReaderSettings()))
```

I receive warning

> CA3075: A potentially insecure XmlReaderSettings instance is provided
>   to XmlReader.Create method.

What is the actual cause of this warning and what is the proper way to make it go away?

I'm using VS 2019 Preview 1.0

I have never seen this warning before and so perhaps it is new with VS 2019?

UPDATE: I have already looked at this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca3075-insecure-dtd-processing?view=vs-2017 and most of the solutions say to set 'XmlReaderSettings(){ DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit }' and I still get the warning.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/1591) might be a duplicate. The issue is not yet marked as fixed.

Comment: @JeroenMostert thanks for this. You might be on to something here!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at the [documentation of the warning](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca3075-insecure-dtd-processing) explains the root cause and many possible fixes, but it boils down that the XML being readed can contain DTD references to potentially insecure places, and a carefully crafted document could represent a vulnerability. From the docs:

> If you use insecure DtdProcessing instances or reference external entity sources, the parser may accept untrusted input and disclose sensitive information to attackers.

The problem lies in that the default settings of both XmlReader and XmlReaderSettings classes allow for such behavior. As the default presents this problem, you need to explictly set to a safe option, that ultimately boils down to setting `DtdProcessing` to `DtdProcessing.Prohibit` or `XmlResolver` to a `XmlSecureResolver`.

Back to your code, it can be changed as such:

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fs, new XmlReaderSettings() { DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Prohibit }))
```

or

```
using (XmlReader xr = XmlReader.Create(fs, new XmlReaderSettings() { XmlResolver = new XmlSecureResolver() }))
```

Comment: I tried both examples and I still get the warning. and the second one requires parameters in the constructor.

Comment: The second example wouldn't work as all constructors of `XmlSecureResolver` require arguments ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlsecureresolver#constructors)).